# What additional conditions/code do I need to add to be able to make the "class list insert code" go green in JUNIT?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, code-coverage, junit5

Below is the image of the code, which is also in the hyperlink "JUNIT," bottom of the page.
I currently have two tests coded for "method: insert" which you can see on the left hand side. I need the main code to go green and also receive 100% coverage, I'm currently on 78%. What do I need to add to make the JUNIT pass?
[JUnIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rROrS.jpg)

```
This is my JUNIT test code: 
 @Test
 public void testInsert() {
     SortedIntegerList list = new SortedIntegerList();
     list.insert(1);
     list.insert(2);
     Integer output = list.getLast();
     assertNotNull(output);
     SortedIntegerList list2 = new SortedIntegerList();
     list2.insert(1);
     list2.insert(2);
     Integer data = 0;
     assertNotNull(data);
 }
 @Test 
 public void testInsertif() { 
     SortedIntegerList list = new SortedIntegerList();
     list.insert(1);
     Integer result = list.getLast();
     assertNotNull(result);
 }
 

 
 @Test 
 public void testInsertwhile() { 
     SortedIntegerList list = new SortedIntegerList();
     list.insert(1);
 }
 



This is the insert Code: 
 public void insert(Integer data) {
        Node curr, foll;

        if ((first == null) || (data <= first.data)) {
            first = new Node(data, first);
        } else {
            curr = first;
            foll = first.next;
            while ((foll != null) && (foll.data < data)) {
                curr = foll;
                foll = foll.next;
            }
            curr.next = new Node(data, foll);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the code to your question. This will make it much more likely that anyone 8s going to provide an answer.

Comment: I have provided it again. I've edited so that the code is contained within my question

Comment: There are many tools that view code coverage data integrated with the source code so it will show exactly which lines are covered, and which are not (Eclipse, for instance). We would have to see that information to be able to possibly answer your question. In any case, of course, your tests are already passing, you're just trying to increase coverage. Note that in general it's not worth the trouble to reach exactly 100% coverage. It may be for this code, but you don't need to aim for 100% in all code.

Comment: In eclipse, right click on test class and select coverage as.  This will give you the details of what are the lines covered and what are left.  Then you can write the code to satisfy those conditions to execute the uncovered lines of code to increase the coverage. Targeting 100% coverage is good but not ideal and no need. I think there must be quality gate for percentage of code coverage in your company.